# Make a 3D tube with a Bézier curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

How can I make a Bézier curve into a 3D-noodle-like structure (like a tube)?
When I try, it keeps turning out like a rectangle with corners.

Comment: Did you see there is a way to make a tree with a built-in addon in Blender? See here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8688/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-a-tree-in-blender

Comment: Great article! Also wrote a similar one that included using this same method but with tapering tubes as well:
[http://benchung.com/making-tubes-blender/](http://benchung.com/making-tubes-blender/)

Comment: You can do simple tapers by adjusting the Radius of control points: Select any control point of the curve in Edit mode, then press Alt+S (Option+S on macOS). See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/editing/curve.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To make a tube, set the *Fill* to full in *Curve > Shape*:

[image]

Then increase the bevel *Depth* and *Resolution* in *Curve > Geometry*:

[image]

If you want a more complex/custom shape, you can use a [bevel object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Geometry):

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!!  I had everything right except the resolution lol. Also how do I make it branch off?

Comment: I just duplicated a segment and then extruded it in another direction. This will work as long as you don't mind the branches not actually being connected to each other, but if you do want them connected, you might want to try using a mesh object with a skin modifier.

Comment: It would be better if you asked this as a separate question, asking multiple questions per post is discouraged.

Answer (score 14):

### Make a Curve into a Tube

1. Add a Curve: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> Curve -> Bezier

   [image]
2. Now add a Circle Curve: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> Curve -> Circle

   [image]
3. Now use the circle as the bevel object for the bezier curve:

   - Select the bezier curve
   - Object Properties window -> Curve tab -> set Bevel Object to the circle
   - Scale the circle until the tube is the size you want

   [image]
4. If you would then like to edit the shape of your tube, just edit the Bevel Object, which here is the circle:

   [image]

Comment: I really like this tutorial! I just wonder, why is there such a big size difference between the "tube" and the bevel object?