# Make a 3D tube with a Bézier curve, bevel not working

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

I'm following the answer of this question: [Make a 3D tube with a Bézier curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/make-a-3d-tube-with-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve)

Now i set the bevel of the curve larger and the curve becomes higher. But there is no tube. It's just flat.

The same thing happens when I used this tutorial: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Modeling/Curves/Making_A_Tube

Here is an image of the problem i face:

[image]

It's not a tube.

**Edit:**
Blender file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40010

Comment: please upload a test blend file

Comment: @Chebhou Updated

Answer (score 2):

the Bevel is working fine just the scale of the curve on X and Y axis is too small (0.05) compared to Z axis scale (1.0)  just fix the scale ( set them all to 1.0 or 0.05) and the bevel effect will be clear