# Make a tube from a straight line

Tags: 3d-view, bevel

I found [this great guide for creating tubes from Bezier curves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/make-a-3d-tube-with-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve), but I am working with an imported set of straight lines that came from a shapefile (geographic data format). I would like to render these as 3D pipes, but this guide seems to only work with Bezier curves.  I do not have the option to change the "Bevel Object" on these straight lines.

[image]

Is there a similar way to just transform all of my straight lines into 3d tubes? I'm not worried about it looking perfect, I just need to see a 3d approximation of them.

Comment: I can't see how your "set of straight lines" is, but I assume they're just lines, no faces, like a "tube map": then for an approximate result you can try to convert them to curves (alt-c in object mode) then use the same approach (bevel object), perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply convert the straight lines **into a curve** then give them the bevel you want.

To convert the straight lines :
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (Select Curve).

By this step the straight lines is converted to curve , so you can easily give it the bevel and control it also as **a curve**.

To give it bevel - When it is a curve - :

[image]

Comment: This created very squashed tubes for me. Also I couldn't scale it normally - it rotated when scaled. (I first converted it back to a mesh using Mesh -> Convert -> Mesh from Curve / …)