# convert multiple lines(except surface) to tubes

Tags: interface

I am working with an imported set of straight lines that came from a shapefile.
I want to convert all the lines(except surface) to tubes at once.

I find [trans one line to one cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90033/make-a-tube-from-a-straight-line). When I select all the object and execute the opration,only one line be converted.

I know the python Scripting can help,but the code may be difficulty. I want to use the blender software to do it.

[image: data]
[image: can not execute opration in multiple line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by

1. select all your objects
2. choose object -> convert to curve

you can see if an object is converted to curve in the outline. It has this symbol in front: [image]

3. Now select all curve objects (don't select other objects)
4. click here: [image]

ALT-Click in Depth:

[image]

enter value (or drag with mouse)

[image]

Comment: My blender version is 3.0.I do the same opration as you.Select all and the opration,but only the last can be change

Comment: Did you hold the CTRL key while clicking in Depth?

Comment: My bad. I try it,but it doesn't work.  ALT-Click works for me.

Comment: maybe my bad -> changed answer to ALT-click