# How to turn a nurbspath into a tube?

Tags: bevel

I am making a gear that has a very unique shape. The tubes will be the teeth. I am doing an experiment to see if something works, and precision is necessary. I have found that i need to use the bevel modifier, but i have no clue how to. I am new to Blender, so i ask of you to share your wisdom with me.
Just to clear things up - it doesnt matter how, but i need a tube to go through a couple designated spots.

Comment: Curves have their own Bevel function in the Object Data Properties. Check this out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/make-a-3d-tube-with-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve . If that doesn't help, some elaboration on what you are trying to do might be needed.

Comment: So, i should just go with bezier instead of nurbspath?

Comment: Okay, i tried it and it worked. Thanks! Bezier it is!

Comment: The example in the link is a Bezier curve but you can find the same setting in the same place for a Nurbs curve, and even somewhat similar ones for a Poly curve. So you still have a choice of preferred curve. : )

Comment: Before i wasnt even aware of that tab. Now i know about it, so im gonna experiment.