# Make a tube shaped like a curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm still trying to understand what I can do with curves and what the limitations are.

I want to be able make a shape, with curves, like this:
[image]
(Not exactly that curve, but it's a good example.)

It's a closed shape. Once I have this shape, I'd like to be able to extrude the shape, like I can with a circle mesh, to make a tube in the shape of that curve. I've read [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8684/101310), which is pre-2.9, so some of what it includes is not doable now. (Or is, but I don't know how to do it.) I know I can convert it to a mesh, but is it possible to take this shape, made out of bezier curves, and make a tube or prism from it without turning it into a mesh?

---

EDIT: After one answer, I think I should clarify: This is a closed curve and, rather than have something like a tube that follows this curve, I want this curve to be a cross section for a tube or prism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go over to the curve icon or **Object Data Properties**- Geometry- and increase the offset, depth and extrude values.

Then you can go to profile, and begin to tweak the bevel profile.  By changing the handle type to vector, and dragging the points upward, you can get a more square profile.

[image]
[image]

You can edit the curve, add points, change the settings,  even switch to draw tool to get a more organic feel.

This is just scratching the surface.

[image]

Comment: I definitely know this is just barely getting into it. I *think* I see what you're saying, but I have to look it over and experiment with it to be sure I get it.

Comment: Okay, after re-reading, I think what I'm asking about is specifically what's in the 3rd image - starting with just a flat curve and adding depth to it.

Comment: Right, just add to the extrude value.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a non closed bezier curve and turn up the *Depth* under *Bevel* will make a tube for you. You can tick the *Fill Caps* box if you want the tube to be closed.

Like this:

[image: Bevel a bezier curve to make pipe]

[image: End result]

Ian Hubert has a fun and helpfull little [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTADG1omjVY) on making pipes in Blender.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a closed (not open) curve and I'm not trying to make a tube that follows the curve, I'm trying to use the curve for the shape of a cross section of the tube.

Comment: Aha, i see. My bad, i misinterpreted your question. I guess common_goldfish might have answered you more properly.

Comment: I think he has answered it - still going through it! (It takes a while to learn anything new on Blender!) But you providing this answer did alert me I had to add something for clarification, so it helped!

Comment: Ah, glad i could be of some help. There is a lot to learn indeed. Good luck!